# How to view more rows of a column in pycharm console

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

How do I view the additional data that is not being displayed in the console?

I do not know where to find this

This is the output on the console., I want to view the data between lines 4 and 2135. How do I do that?

0       False
1       False
2       False
3       False
4       False
        ...
2135    False
2136    False
2137    False
2138    False
2139    False
Name: Case_Date, Length: 2140, dtype: bool

No error messages. It just hides the print information behind ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd    
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
```

Comment: Thank you, simple but very helpful for me. I am unable to upvote yet because this: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." Otherwise I would upvote it. Works perfectly

Comment: You should be able to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Thanks that is my first time doing that